# Regex for Two Words case Insensitive

Tags: regex, hadoop, apache-pig

How can I write a regex statement for finding the words "Air Canada" case-insensitive that may or may not have a whitespace character between the words? I'm using this statement in Pig.

Here is what I've tried:

```
[Aa][Ii][Rr]*\s[Cc][Aa][Nn][Aa][Dd][Aa]
```

I also tried:

```
(air)*\s(canada) \i
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try turning the `s` and the `*` around like `\s*` or else the quantifier is for the character class `[Rr]*` to match 1+ times R or r and then match a whitespace char  \s

Comment: You can use `(?i)air ?canada` or `(?i)air *canada` assuming more than one space is possible.